# How to print the complete output line relevant to the given input?

Tags: go, input

In this code, I am finding the data from a file and it is also giving me the result that I search. That means it only prints the name or phone number. But I want to print the whole line(s) in which a  particular name or phone number is present.

```
func readFile() {
    var searchData string
    fmt.Printf("Enter the name or phone number to search: ")
    fmt.Scanln(&searchData)

    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("data.csv")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    suffix := suffixarray.New(content)
    indexList := suffix.Lookup([]byte(searchData), -1)
    if len(indexList) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("Data is not found")
        return
    }
    data := string(content)
    for _, idx := range indexList {
        fmt.Println("Data is found:", string(data[idx:idx+len(searchData)]))
        fmt.Println(data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the location part-way into a line, you can scan backwards from there to find either the previous \n, or the start of the file. Similarly, you can scan forwards from there to find either the next \n or the end of the file. These two endpoints will give you the complete line that contains the given index.

Something like this (untested):

```
start := idx
for start >= 0 && data[start] != '\n' {
    start--
}
end := idx
for end < len(data) && data[end] != '\n' {
    end++
}
fmt.Println(string(data[start+1:end]))
```

You can also write it using the `bytes` package using `LastIndexByte` and `IndexByte`, but you have to handle the case where \n isn't found after the index point.

```
start := bytes.LastIndexByte(data[:idx], '\n')
end := bytes.IndexByte(data[idx:], '\n') + idx
if end == idx - 1 { end = len(data) }
fmt.Println(string(data[start+1:end]))
```